# Inno Setup is not including any of indicated files in destination folder

Tags: inno-setup

This is the first time I've used an installer program other than Access Developer Extensions. I have couple of MS Access files I'm trying to have installed into the user's AppData\Local folder. The only thing it will seem to do is put two files in that folder: unins000.exe and unins000.dat. It seems to ignore the files I want put in there, although when I compile it's definitely including them in the Setup.exe file. Here is the script - can someone tell me what could be wrong here? It doesn't seem to matter if the destination folder or files exist or not - I get the same result.

```
; -- LEAP.iss --

[Setup]
AppName=LEAP
AppVersion=1.1
DefaultDirName={localappdata}\LEAP
DefaultGroupName=LEAP
Compression=lzma2
SolidCompression=yes
OutputDir=userdocs:Inno Setup Output

[Files]
Source: "China.accdb"; DestDir: "{localappdata}"; DestName: "China.accdr"
Source: "Replica of China_be.mdb"; DestDir: "{localappdata}"

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\LEAP"; Filename: "{localappdata}\China.accdr"
Name: "{userdesktop}\LEAP"; Filename: "{localappdata}\China.accdr"
```

Answer (score 6):

You want to replace `{localappdata}` with `{app}` in the `[Files]` and `[Icons]` sections. The `{app}` constant is defined once the user selects the install location on the "**Select Destination Location**" wizard page. Your end-users might not appreciate that you've allow them to choose a location to install your program, only to find out that you've actually hard-coded that location in the installer.

If you don't want them to choose a location, then set [`DisableDirPage=true`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_disabledirpage) in `[Setup]`.

You should also establish an [AppID](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_appid) value in [Setup].

Comment: OK, I don't want them to choose the location, so that's helpful, but if I want the files to go into their local AppData folder, why would I use {app}? Wouldn't that put them in Program Files? Or do you think that's really why it's not putting the files there as it should? Like it doesn't want to put them in {localappdata} for some reason?

Comment: `{app}` expands to whatever the user puts into the Select Destination Location wizard page, which in turn defaults to whatever you've set `DefaultDirName` to.  Since you've already set that to `{localappdata}\LEAP`, then that's what that will default to, and you should be using it.  Note however that installing to a per-user folder like this means that you MUST also use `PrivilegesRequired=lowest`.